# Потоки, JavaFX и обработчик событий

Tags: многопоточность, javafx

У меня есть два потока(главный и одни побочный). При нажатии на кнопку побочный поток выполняется но при повторном нажатии ошибка.Ниже приведен код.Необходимо чтобы можно было нажать на кнопку подождать пока поток выполнится и еще раз нажать и чтобы поток еще раз выполнился.

```
 package application;
 import javax.sound.midi.MidiChannel;
 import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
 import javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer;
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.control.Button;
 import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;
 public class Main extends Application {
     static AffableThread mSecondThread; //побочный поток
     public void start(Stage stage) {
         AnchorPane r1 = new AnchorPane(); //создание pane
         Scene sc1 = new Scene(r1, 600, 400); //создание сцены
         mSecondThread = new AffableThread(); //Создание потока
         Button b1 = new Button(); //та самая кнопка
         b1.setLayoutX(200);
         b1.setLayoutY(100);
         b1.setPrefSize(100, 50);
         r1.getChildren().add(b1);
         b1.setOnAction(b - > { //ActionListener
             mSecondThread.start(); //начало потока
         });
         stage.setScene(sc1);
         stage.show();
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
         System.out.println("Главный поток завершён...");
     }
     class AffableThread extends Thread //вложенный класс отвечающий за то что происходит в побочном потоке
     {@
         Override
         public void run() //Этот метод будет выполнен в побочном потоке
         {
             System.out.println("Привет из побочного потока!");
             System.out.println("Привет из побочного потока!");
             try {
                 Synthesizer s1 = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
                 s1.open();
                 MidiChannel[] channels = s1.getChannels();
                 channels[0].programChange(41);
                 channels[0].noteOn(36, 80);
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 channels[0].noteOff(36);
                 channels[0].noteOn(38, 80);
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 channels[0].noteOff(38);
                 channels[0].noteOn(40, 80);
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 channels[0].noteOff(40);
                 channels[0].noteOn(41, 80);
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 channels[0].noteOff(41);
                 channels[0].noteOn(43, 80);
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 channels[0].noteOff(43);
                 channels[0].noteOn(45, 80);
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 channels[0].noteOff(45);
                 channels[0].noteOn(47, 80);
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 channels[0].noteOff(47);
                 s1.close();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: RTFM java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService

Answer (score 1):

Если совсем по простому, то можно создавать поток каждый раз при нажатии кнопки:

```
b1.setOnAction(b -> { //ActionListener
    if ( mSecondThread == null || !mSecondThread.isAlive() ) {
        mSecondThread = new AffableThread(); //Создание потока
        mSecondThread.start(); //начало потока
    }
});
```

Можно как советовал Yura Ivanov:

```
import javax.sound.midi.MidiChannel;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main extends Application {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    private ScheduledFuture future = null;

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        AnchorPane r1 = new AnchorPane();
        Scene sc1 = new Scene(r1, 600, 400);
        Button b1 = new Button();
        b1.setLayoutX(200);
        b1.setLayoutY(100);
        b1.setPrefSize(100, 50);
        r1.getChildren().add(b1);
        b1.setOnAction(b -> {
        if ( future == null || future.isDone() ) {
            try {
                future = executor.schedule( runnable, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
            } catch( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(sc1);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        System.out.println("Главный поток завершён...");
    }

    private Runnable runnable = () -> {
        System.out.println("Привет из побочного потока!");
        System.out.println("Привет из побочного потока!");
        try {
            Synthesizer s1 = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
            s1.open();
            MidiChannel[] channels = s1.getChannels();
            channels[0].programChange(41);
            channels[0].noteOn(36, 80);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            channels[0].noteOff(36);
            channels[0].noteOn(38, 80);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            channels[0].noteOff(38);
            channels[0].noteOn(40, 80);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            channels[0].noteOff(40);
            channels[0].noteOn(41, 80);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            channels[0].noteOff(41);
            channels[0].noteOn(43, 80);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            channels[0].noteOff(43);
            channels[0].noteOn(45, 80);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            channels[0].noteOff(45);
            channels[0].noteOn(47, 80);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            channels[0].noteOff(47);
            s1.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

}
```

Написано не идеально, но направление верное.
Также можно глянуть в сторону javafx.concurrent, хотя в данном случае это будет лишним.

Comment: Лишним знакомство с javafx.concurrent точно не будет.